# SwiftUI List rows that contain a DatePicker are taller on a physical device than they are on the simulator

Tags: swiftui

In this test app, `List` rows that contain a `DatePicker` are taller on a physical device than they are on the simulator.

List Row Heights:

| Row Contents | Simulator | Device |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text | 36 | 36 |
| DatePicker | 36 | 52 |

Also, using `.listRowInsets(.init())` on a row with a `DatePicker` increases the row height on a simulator from 36 to 44, which seems odd.

Is there a way to make the simulator and physical device have the same behavior (ideally the simulator's)? I don't believe I have any accessibility settings changed from the default. Screenshots attached.

If `listRowInsets()` is the way to proceed, is there a way to either:

1. only apply top and bottom insets so that the default leading and trailing insets are used?
2. get the default leading and trailing insets so they can be used?

I tested this on physical and simulator iPhone 13s with iOS 17.2.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Text")
                
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("\(geometry.size.height)")
                }
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Date")

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("\(geometry.size.height)")
                }
                    
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $date,
                    displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute
                )
                .fixedSize()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text("Date 0 Insets")

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("\(geometry.size.height)")
                }
                    
                DatePicker(
                    "",
                    selection: $date,
                    displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute
                )
                .fixedSize()
            }
            .listRowInsets(.init())
        }
    }
}
```

Device Screenshot
[image: Device Screenshot]

Simulator Screenshot
[image: Simulator Screenshot]

Device Accessibility Settings Screenshots
[image: Device Accessibility Settings Screenshot 1]
[image: Device Accessibility Settings Screenshot 2]

Comment: Check the text size on the device in the accessibility settings. You got as far as the page before this, but you need to tap the arrow to the right where it says Larger Text: Off. Larger Text makes it possible to have extra-large text, but It's possible to set a larger size with Larger Text still off.